# Sharepoint 2010: Restricting Users to only view document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a query regarding viewing documents in sharepoint 2010. Basically I need to send a link to another user (employee)in another department to view the document. However i do not want him to view any other documents or be able to navigate to any other document library or folder or root directory/site?
What is the best approcah?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case you want the user to view only that document then you have to set permission on that document, a minimum of read-only permission. You should remove access of this user from other documents and other document libraries. Basically you have to break the inheritance of document lib permission. This is the easiest out of the box approach you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is by setting specific permissions to that user or group in the file or folder you want to give access. All other site/object permissions should not include this user or group.

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box approach is break the permissions to the document.

1. Go to the document permissions.
2. Click "Stop Inheriting Permissions" option from the ribbon.
3. Add a user you want to grant "Read" permissions.

This will make sure the user can access only that document.